# Context Timeout for Redirects rather than using Client Timeouts?

Tags: redirect, go, timeout, httprequest

I perform an HTTP request from a client with an explicit `http.Client.Timeout`

```
client := http.Client{
    Timeout: timeout, // 5 seconds
}

httpResponse, err := client.Do(httpRequest)
```

But this client will perform a series of redirects (I'm not sure how many).

From what I understand, each redirect will restart the timeout, so the timeout of 5 seconds will be `five-seconds * num-of-redirects`.

Is it possible to **rather pass in the timeout inside a `context.Context`**?

```
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
// do I need cancel?
httpRequest.WithContext(ctx)
httpResponse, err := client.Do(httpRequest)
```

Would this encompass the request **and all redirects** in the same timeout? Or do I misunderstand redirects/timeouts/contexts?

Comment: In the docs they say you need to call the cancel function no matter what. They have an example showing a `defer cancel()` to make sure of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like each redirect will reset the `http.Client` time out.

From the net/http documentation:

```
// Timeout specifies a time limit for requests made by this
// Client. The timeout includes connection time, any
// redirects, and reading the response body.
```

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

Comment: It seems it work work as well, see this related question for an example and further explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321894/context-timeout-implementation-on-every-request-using-golang