# Implement context timeout on http server request

Tags: go

How to implement a 60 second context timeout on http server requests? One type of the handlers already has a context with value applied

I can't wrap my head around how to implement it in the best way

Found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43322359/555222

How to stop the http request handler from continuing executing if timeout is reached?

## original code before implementation

```
srv := &http.Server{
    Addr:               fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", h.host, h.port),
    Handler:            http.HandlerFunc(h.serve),
}
err := srv.ListenAndServe()

...

func (h *HTTP) serve(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var allow []string
    for _, route := range h.routes {
        if route.regex != nil {
            //  Regex path
            matches := route.regex.FindStringSubmatch(r.URL.Path)
            len     := len(matches)
            if len > 0 {
                if len == 1 {
                    route.handler(w, r)  // ADD CONTEXT TIMEOUT 60 SECS
                }else{
                    //  Context with value
                    ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), ctx_http, matches[1:])
                    route.handler(w, r.WithContext(ctx))  // ADD CONTEXT TIMEOUT 60 SECS
                }
                return
            }
        }else{
            //  Path
            if strings.HasPrefix(r.URL.Path, route.path) {
                route.handler(w, r)  // ADD CONTEXT TIMEOUT 60 SECS
                return
            }
        }
    }
    
    http.Error(w, "Not found", http.StatusNotFound)
}
```

## code after implementation (not working)

This is what I would expect to work

- 10 sec sleep in the http request handler
- 2 sec context timeout

**What works**

- If the request exceeds the 2 secs timeout a `HTTP 408` is returned and connection is closed (as expected)

**What doesn't work**

- If the request exceeds the timeout the http request handler continues to execute and prints `req executed` 8 secs AFTER the timeout

output

```
2023-08-28 20:14:47 context timeout exceeded
2023-08-28 20:14:47 cancel
2023-08-28 20:14:55 req completed
```

code

```
func (h *HTTP) serve(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(r.Context(), time.Duration(2 * time.Second))
    defer func(){
        fmt.Println(time.Now(), "cancel")
        cancel()
    }()
    
    go func(){
        for _, route := range h.routes {
            if route.regex != nil {
                //  Regex path
                matches := route.regex.FindStringSubmatch(r.URL.Path)
                len     := len(matches)
                if len > 0 {
                    //  Slug group capture
                    if len > 1 {
                        ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, ctx_http, matches[1:])
                    }
                    
                    route.handler(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
                    cancel()
                    return
                }
            }else{
                //  Path
                if strings.HasPrefix(r.URL.Path, route.path) {
                    route.handler(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
                    cancel()
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        
        http.Error(w, "Not found", http.StatusNotFound)
        cancel()
    }()
    
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        switch ctx.Err() {
        case context.DeadlineExceeded:
            fmt.Println(time.Now(), "context timeout exceeded")
            http.Error(w, "Timeout", http.StatusRequestTimeout)
        case context.Canceled:
            fmt.Println(time.Now(), "context cancelled by force. whole process is complete")
        }
    }
}
```

http request handler

```
h.Route(serv.ALL, "/timeout", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    defer serv.Recover(w)
    
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(time.Now(), "req completed")
    
    io.WriteString(w, "timeout test")
})
```

Comment: Seems like it's not possible to interupt a goroutine https://stackoverflow.com/a/58633357/555222

Answer (score 0):

The question explicitly asks about creating a timeout context, but comments by the OP indicate that they want to timeout the request without using a context.  To do that, wrap the root handler in OP's orginal code with a [timeout handler](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#TimeoutHandler):

```
srv := &http.Server{
    Addr:               fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", h.host, h.port),
    Handler:            http.TimeoutHandler(http.HandlerFunc(h.serve), 60 * time.Second, "xyprob"),
}
```

---

Here's the answer to the question as asked.

Use the following code to implement context timeout on an HTTP request:

```
func (h *HTTP) serve(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(r.Context(), time.Duration(2*time.Second))
    defer cancel()
    var allow []string
    for _, route := range h.routes {
        if route.regex != nil {
            //  Regex path
            matches := route.regex.FindStringSubmatch(r.URL.Path)
            len := len(matches)
            if len > 0 {
                //  Group captures
                if len > 1 {
                    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, ctx_http, matches[1:])
                }

                route.handler(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
                return
            }
        } else {
            //  Path
            if strings.HasPrefix(r.URL.Path, route.path) {
                route.handler(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
                return
            }
        }
    }
    if len(allow) > 0 {
        w.Header().Set("Allow", strings.Join(allow, ", "))
        http.Error(w, "Method not allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }
    http.Error(w, "Not found", http.StatusNotFound)
}
```

Use the context in the handler:

```
h.Route(serv.ALL, "/timeout", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    defer serv.Recover(w)

    // Sleep for 10 seconds or wait for context to cancel.
    select {
    case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
    case <-r.Context().Done():
        http.Error(w, "Timeout", http.StatusRequestTimeout)
        return
    }
        
    fmt.Println(time.Now(), "req completed")
    io.WriteString(w, "timeout test")
})
```

Comment: The timeout should not be handled from inside the http request

Comment: `http.TimeoutHandler` does not interupt the handler execution on the server but only send a response back to the client. That part I already handle by the contect timeout in my code. The problem is I have to stop the execution of the request handler itself

Comment: if you set `http.TimeoutHandler` then all requests will have the same timeout which is not very flexible. Some requests need more time to complete

Comment: seems like it's not possible to interupt a goroutine https://stackoverflow.com/a/58633357/555222

Comment: @clarkk I followed the code in the question by applying the same timeout to all handlers.  Wrap the individual handlers instead of the root handler to get a timeout per handler.

Comment: @clarkk My answer shows your two choices: use context to cooperatively timeout handler functions or send a response back without waiting for the handler.

Answer (score -1):

You can add Timeouts to contexts using [WithTimout](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithTimeout) and you can pass the context through the request using `r.WithContext(ctx)` like you did in one of the cases.